# How do I prove that |A| - |A\B| = |A∩B|

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to prove that |A| - |A\B| = |A∩B| by the following identities:

1. |A| + |B| - |A⋃B| = |A∩B|
2. A\B = A(A∩B)
3. A∩B = A(A\B)
4. (A⋃B)\B = A\B
5. A⋃B = A⋃(B\A)

I can't figure out what to do, I would be glad to get some help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use that for $A,B \subset \Omega$ we have $A \setminus B = A \cap B^{\complement}$.

Comment: Also, A∩B = A(A\B) doesn't really make sense, I suspect you are missing an operator there. The same goes for the second statement.

Comment: The notation $|A|$ likely means the size or *cardinality* of set $A$.  While that may be known to you, it is worth pointing out that since your conclusion involves that notation, and since only "identity" 1. uses that notation among the ones listed, that first identify will need to be used in your proof.  So that's a place to start.  I suspect that the setup for this exercise specified that the sets $A,B$ are finite, and you should look for steps in which their finiteness is important to the argument.

Comment: In identity 3 I meant to A∩B = A \ (A\B)

Comment: @hardmath You’re right, I misread

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$ A=(A\cap B) \cup (A-B)$$

The sets on the RHS are disjoint so $$|A|=|A\cap B)|+|A-B|$$

Answer (score 0):

By using the fact that $|A\setminus B|=|A\cap \overline{B}|$ this becomes
$$|A\cap \overline{B}|+|A\cap B|=|A|$$
then, applying identity $1$ on the LHS,
$$|(A\cap \overline{B})\cup(A\cap B)|+|(A\cap \overline{B})\cap(A\cap B)|=|A|$$
$$|A|+|\varnothing|=|A|$$
which is true.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to figure it out, thanks again.